Invoking a Per User Named Credential OAuth flow on click of a button
Here is my use Case.
I am trying to connect Salesforce with another Salesforce org with Per User Identity Type.
The Second Salesforce org is just to demonstrate that the process works and will eventually be replaced by an external provider.
I have configured

A Salesforce AUTH provider with client id, client secret and scopes
a Named Credential to use the authprovider with protocol OAuth 2.0, type = Per User

I want to invoke this on a click of a button by current logged in User and not via user settings > Authentication Settings for External Systems
I understand to do that I need to manipulate the ExternalDataUserAuth and I have followed the steps mentioned in this answer(How can I programmatically send users through a Per User Named Credential OAuth flow without directly calling the Metadata API?)
Current Situation

I have created a VF page with the button "Click To Authorize". The startURL is set to return back to the ExternalDataUserAuth record
Clicking the button correctly opens up the login screen for the Second Salesforce org.
User successfully logins and SF redirects back to the startURL
The ExternalDataUserAuth record status is, however, still PENDING.
Any subsequent API calls, therefore, fail.

Manually going to user settings > Authentication Settings for External Systems and doing the same process correctly sets the status as Connected.
I have even followed the new Connect API and this example provided by Salesforce (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/named-credentials/guide/nc-create-oauth-cred.html) but to no avail.
Can anyone please point to what is missing in my setup or have successfully solved this?
